TSC Print from flutter app using local network
i have to do print pdf from flutter app to TSC printer. is anyone that have any idea about it then give some replay. app platform is android and ios only.

Yes you can print PDF from flutter app to TCS printer but that operation require socket connection so you first connect to the socket and command execute to print pdf to printer.
